# Generating test email ids

Tags: javascript

Required solution for a problem:

Id is fixed ‘qualityassurance’ I want to generate ids like: `1- q.ualityassurance`

For second run id should be like: `2- qu.alityassurance`

For third run it should be like: `3- qua.lityassurance`

and so on till id’s length. But i dont understand how to recall function for next run with incremented value.

Code is:

```
Selenium.prototype.doNothing = function(){
    // The do in front of Nothing in the function is what tells the system this is a global function
}

Selenium.prototype.doRandomEmail = function(locator, num)
{
    var id = “qualityassurancetask”;
    var stringLength = id.length;
    var randomstring = ”;
    var insstring = ‘.’;
    var num = 1;

    //var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * stringLength);

    var remainingstring = id.substring(num,id.length);

    randomstring += id.substring(0,num).concat(insstring, remainingstring);
    randomstring += “@gmail.com”

    num= num+1;

    selenium.doType(locator,randomstring,num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
next_address = last_address.replace(/\.(.)/, "$1.");
```

The idea is to look for ".?" where ? is any character (note that the literal . in the regex is used to match any character, hence my use of .? to explain).  This is changed to "?.", i.e. the dot is "pushed" rightward in the string.  If the new and old addresses are identical, then you've run out of combinations.

Note if your address strings contain the @gmail.com part, you need to avoid moving the dot past the @, which you can do like this:

```
next_address = last_address.replace(/\.(\w)/, "$1.");
```

That is, only allow swapping the dot with "word" characters.